# ReactJS GUI State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component which renders a bunch of collapsible menus based on an initial configuration object. The object is in JSON, but the menu tree structure might look something like this:

```
Group A
  - Item 1
  - Item 2
  - Item 3

Group B
  - Item 4
  - Item 5
  - Item 6
  - Item 7
```

A user can click on a header object e.g. `Group A` and it will collapse/expand the group - essentially an accordion.

Each *group* component has a limited number of properties, props and state look something like this:

```
getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
        title: '',
        itemsList: [],
        initiallyOpened: true
    };
},

getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        isOpened: this.props.initiallyOpened
    };
}
```

When the user clicks on a group heading, I toggle the isOpened property in state.

This works perfectly fine for allowing the user to open/close groups, but I'd also like some *global* behaviors such as *open all* or *close all*.

I know that I can explicitly set the `initiallyOpened` prop, which will trigger a `componentWillReceiveProps()` call, but I don't want that value of `initiallyOpened` to persist when the component receives some other new props (maybe a new item is added to the list).

Where and how should I be handling the management of this GUI state?

Answer (score -1):

The recommended way of managing global state in React is to employ an architecture pattern called [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/).

It has many [implementations](https://github.com/voronianski/flux-comparison).